# Vue2 how export multiple components as library that use Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

i'm trying to export a Vue.js 2 project as a library containing multiple components.

Using [this](https://itnext.io/create-a-vue-js-component-library-part-2-c92a42af84e9) as example I managed to export a single component.

In my "library" project, I've exported in the main.js:

```js
import TestButton from "@/components/TestButton";
import store from "@/store";

export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    if (!options || !options.store) {
      throw new Error("Please initialise plugin with a Vuex store.");
    }

    options.store.registerModule("testLibrary", store);

    Vue.component("test-button", TestButton);
  }
};
```

I build it via `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name testlib src/main.js`

Published on npm via `npm publish --access-public`

And then imported in another Vue 2 project.

Here in the main.js I've:

```js
[...]
new Vue({
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");

import TestButton from "my-test-library";

Vue.use(TestButton, { store });
```

And then I can successfully use `<test-button></test-button>`  in whatever component I need, while the Vuex Store has a working "testLibrary" module.

Now the question is how I can export multiple components in the first app and import in the second one.

I've found many example about, such as [this one](https://dev.to/siegerts/creating-a-vue-js-component-library-part-i-introduction-2o9f), however I can't get it working.

For example, in the library app I'm trying

```js
import TestButton from "@/components/TestButton";
import AnotherComponent "@/components/AnotherComponent";

import store from "@/store";
export default {
  install(Vue, options) {
    if (!options || !options.store) {
      throw new Error("Please initialise plugin with a Vuex store.");
    }

    options.store.registerModule("testLibrary", store);

    Vue.component("test-button", TestButton);
    Vue.component("another-component", AnotherComponent);
  }
};
```

While in the second app I'm trying something like

```js
[...]
import { TestButton, AnotherComponent } from "my-test-library";
```

But whatever syntax I try it seems like the second app goes in a loop while building and don't work.

Any idea how is this done?

Comment: To export some components, you need to specify the main entry point in the first app's package.json, then export them in the entry point. Now, you can import them in the second app separately.

Comment: Your plugin globally registers the two components, so you could use them without registering them in your second app. If you need to locally register them instead, your library would need to expor the components (which it currently doesn't).